# Counting the number of equivalent words (having the same letters, with the same order of vowels)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

2 words are considered to be equivalent of they have the same order of vowels and the same alphabets and the same number of alphabets as in the original word.
Find the number of equivalent words of BACHELOR.

I think I can consider the vowels to be placed as in the original word and then place the remaining letters between the vowels.
but then how should I place the letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question as stated has a simple answer: $\infty$. All the "words"
$$BACHELORRRRR\ldots R$$
have the same order of vowels and the same alphabet. If you are actually looking for an order-preserving permutation, you should edit your question and tell what your thoughts are.

---

The question as is is probably meant${}^\text{TM}$ can be solved as follows:

> BACHELOR contains the vowels A,E,O in order so
>
> 1. Select the positions for A, E, O (order doesn't matter since it's dictated by the equivalence)
> 2. Permute the remaining letters in the remaining slots. There are no duplicate letters so this will be very easy.

Comment: check the q now

Comment: Lol'd. You mean number of _letters_. Both words have one alphabet :P Also, **tell us what your thoughts are** was a serious request.